# Django Sum all values with a distinct ForeignKey ID & zip them with fields from related table

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I would like to perform something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861310/summing-the-values-from-the-2nd-table-based-on-id-of-the-1st-table) (ie get the sum of distinct event amounts in a payment table then group the payments by event details and total money paid for them. Also getting users and what they have paid for an event will be done) in Django using PostgreSQL.

My models are as below:

```
class UserProfile(User):
    onames = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    regNo = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=3,choices=DESIGNATION_CHOICES, default='MEM')
    image = models.ImageField(max_length=100,upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True, null=True, default='photos/2010/03/placeholder.jpg')
    course = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Africa/Nairobi')
    smsCom = models.BooleanField()
    mailCom = models.BooleanField()

class Payments(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='payer')
    receiptNo = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    particulars = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    amount = models.FloatField(max_length=99, blank=True)
    eventID = models.ForeignKey('events', null=True, blank=True)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='receiver')
    deleted = models.BooleanField()

class events(models.Model):
    eventName  = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    eventID =  models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    details = models.TextField()
    attendanceFee = models.FloatField(max_length=99)
    date = models.DateField()
    username = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, related_name='user')
    eventposter = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='event_poster')
    deleted = models.BooleanField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some nerve cracking, the solution was to split the query into 2, i.e, one for grouping and summing and the other one for getting the matching values.

For grouping and summing, refer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django)